# count sequence of value in df

Tags: python, pandas

I have df:

```
id  color val
1     y    3
1     y    3
1     y    3
2     y    1
2     r    2
```

I want to count the condition that the value in val column is <=3 at least 3 times in the same id and color in a row(in sequence), and when the condition is true, to return the id and color.
for example I will get here 1,y
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
N = 3 # number consecutive matches
s = (df['val'].le(3) # condition: value ≤ 3
 .groupby([df['id'], df['color']]) # make groups
 # is there any occurrence where there are N True in a row?
 .apply(lambda s: s.rolling(N).sum().eq(N).any())
)

# keep only the True and convert to list
s[s].index.to_list()
```

output: `[(1, 'y')]`

intermediate `s`:

```
id  color
1   y         True
2   r        False
    y        False
Name: val, dtype: bool
```

Comment: why do you choose sum instead of count?

Comment: because we have booleans, summing the array of True/False is the same as counting the True

Comment: how can I return in 's' more column in the df?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby` and `filter`

```py
cols = ['id', 'color']
out = (df.groupby(cols)
       .filter(lambda df: df['val'].le(3).sum() >= 3)
       .drop_duplicates(cols)[cols])
```

```
print(out)

   id color
0   1     y
```